# Can I have two @ClientCacheApplication in the same Spring Boot Application?

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Can I have two `@ClientCacheApplication` instances in the same *Spring Boot* application?

I have two classes: `PeopleDataAccess` and `JobDataAccess`. Both of them are a `@ClientCacheApplication`.

```
@Service
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "AccessingDataGemFireApplication", logLevel = "error")
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = People.class, clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.LOCAL)
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = PeopleRepository.class)
public class PeopleDataAccess {

  @Autowired
  PeopleRepository peopleRepository;

  public void saveRecord() {
    People alice = new People("Adult Alice", 40);
    People bob = new People("Baby Bob", 1);
    People carol = new People("Teen Carol", 13);
    peopleRepository.save(alice);
    peopleRepository.save(bob);
    peopleRepository.save(carol);
  }
}


@Service
@ClientCacheApplication(name = "AccessingDataGemFireApplication", logLevel = "error")
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = Job.class, clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.LOCAL)
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = JobRepository.class)
public class JobDataAccess {

  @Autowired
  JobRepository jobRepository;

  public void saveRecord() {
    Job firemen = new Job("Firemen");
    Job accounting = new Job("Accounting");
    jobRepository.save(firemen);
    jobRepository.save(accounting);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer... No.  With Pivotal GemFire/Apache Geode, any cache instance (whether a [`ClientCache`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/client/ClientCache.html) or a peer [`Cache`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Cache.html) (used server-side)) is a *Singleton*.  That is, there can only be 1 instance per JVM.

Maybe if you describe your UC and what you are trying to accomplish I can provide more direction?

Comment: I want to create multi module library project with spring boot for gemfire data access. For example , spring boot application A, spring boot application B and spring boot application C calling the same module library. Application A is calling JobDataAccess , application B is calling PeopleDataAccess and application C is calling both JobDataAccess and PeopleDataAccess. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Let me rephrase my answer slightly.  There are no issues using the `@ClientCacheApplication` annotation on multiple components in the same (Spring Boot) application.  In that case it will simply hand you the existing `ClientCache` instance created by whatever `@ClientCacheApplication` annotation component tripped the configuration of a `ClientCache` instance first.  It's just that you should not think you will have multiple `ClientCache` instances in this case given GemFire/Geode restricts the cache to being a "Singleton".  This is of little consequence though...

Comment: By way of example, I wrote a simple test that is not unlike your application configuration arrangement.  See here: https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/data/gemfire/MultiClientCacheApplicationIntegrationTests.java.  It does not use SD Repositories and is not separated into multiple modules, but that is of no matter to illustrate that what you are doing is fine.

Comment: If you are shooting for a bit more isolation between components/modules, then GemFire/Geode additionally offers the concept of Groups.  Of course, on the server-side, your corresponding server Regions (People, Job) can be hosted by certain members in the cluster (not all members need to host all Regions).  These members can then be placed into Groups.  Then, on the client, you can create multiple Pools assigned to a certain Group and then initialize a client Region to a Pool in a particular Group.  Of course, there are other arrangements as well.  This is just 1 idea.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Are they any issue in using @EnableGemfireRepositories annotation on multiple component in the same spring boot application? When i run the above the example code above, it always stop immediately after displaying the spring boot logo. When i comment out the @EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = JobRepository.class) , it will able to detect the rest of component.

Comment: I think it is due to GemfireMappingContext. I tried to create a configuration class to create bean to get GemfireMappingContext. Then, change to @EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repo.people"}, mappingContextRef = "gemfireMappingContext") from @EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.repo.people"}) solve the issue.